# Core Data and NSSortDescriptor - memory basics

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to a sort on a Core Data entity's relation. For instance there is an employee object and it has departments relationship.

1. I do a NSFetchRequest of employee
2. I write a method to take out `departments` (`NSSet`) and it gets me sorted departments

The code I'm using is the following.

```
[tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

I see memory getting retained even after sometime and also the Core Data object in that getting retained after so long time.

I removed this line thinking that could be the reason

`//[moc setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES];`

but that is not helping. I want to understand will all objects method on a `NSSet` of Core Data object cause bump in memory and also `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors` do deep copy?
I know it is a shallow copy, please confirm and what could be the logical reason for memory getting retained even after usage of the array of object got using `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`.

Comment: First you should make your question clear. Also you should format it in the correct manner. Then, are you using ARC or not? Finally, where do you see that big memory footprint?

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in my comment, you should provide some context for your question. So, did you see this behavior in Instrument?

Anyway, instead of fetching and then sorting, you can fetch and, at the same time, sort (through `NSFetchRequest` using `setSortDescriptors:`) against `Department` based on specific predicate (if I well understood your problem the predicate will give you the departments that belong to a specific employee). In this way the sorting is done at the SQL level.

You should also provide the code you are using concerning

```
[tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

What about `sortDescriptor`? If you are not using ARC, you `alloc-init` a new `sortDescriptor` you must dealloc it. Otherwise you will have a leak.